# C under Ubuntu - not expected result trying to solve "Wheel game"

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

The wheel. The main process (A) will create a subprocess (B) that will create another subprocess (C).
Then the main process (A) will send the generate a random number (between 1000 and 2000) to process B.
The process B will subtract 10 units and will send the number to process C. C will subtract 20 units and will
send the number to A. The A process will subtract 30 units and will send the number to B, again. And so on,
until the values is less than zero. In this moment the game will stop. The winner is the process that established
the negative number.

The communication between all the processes are done using pipe channels.

My solution was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int pass(char* id, int in, int out, int x)
{
  int n;
  read(in, &n, sizeof(int));
  printf("%s %d\n", id, n);
  n=n-x;
  printf("x= %d\n", x);
  write(out, &n, sizeof(int));
  return n;
}


void closeall(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
  close(a[0]);
  close(a[1]);
  close(b[0]);
  close(b[1]);
  close(c[0]);
  close(c[1]);
}



int main()

{
  int a2b[2], b2c[2], c2a[2], n, x;
  pipe(a2b);
  pipe(b2c);
  pipe(c2a);

  srand(time(NULL));
  n=rand() % 1001 + 1000;
  x=0;

  write(c2a[1], &n, sizeof(int));

  if (fork() == 0){
    while (pass("grandfather ", c2a[0], a2b[1], x) > 0){
            x=x+10;}
    exit(0);

  }

  if (fork() == 0){
    while (pass("father ", a2b[0], b2c[1], x) > 0){
        x=x+10;}
    exit(0);
  }


  if (fork() == 0){
    while (pass("child ", b2c[0], c2a[1], x) > 0){
        x=x+10;}
    exit(0);
  }

  closeall(a2b, b2c,c2a);

  wait(0);
  wait(0);
  wait(0);
  return 0;
}
```

After running the program the result was

```
grandfather  1420
x= 0
father  1420
x= 0
child  1420
x= 0
grandfather  1420
x= 10
father  1410
x= 10
child  1400
x= 10
grandfather  1390
x= 20
father  1370
x= 20
child  1350
x= 20
grandfather  1330
x= 30
father  1300
x= 30
child  1270
x= 30
grandfather  1240
x= 40
father  1200
x= 40
child  1160
x= 40
grandfather  1120
x= 50
father  1070
x= 50
child  1020
x= 50
grandfather  970
x= 60
father  910
x= 60
child  850
x= 60
grandfather  790
x= 70
father  720
x= 70
child  650
x= 70
grandfather  580
x= 80
father  500
x= 80
child  420
x= 80
grandfather  340
x= 90
father  250
x= 90
child  160
x= 90
grandfather  70
x= 100
father  -30
x= 100
child  -130
x= 100
```

Can someone help me improve the source code in order to obtain the correct result? As seen before, the subtracted value of x is the same for three times, and it doesn't stop after the first negative number.

Comment: from `correct code` to `correct code but better by some metric` = `improvement`. From `incorrect code` to `correct code` = `fix`

Comment: You are right. How can I fix the code ? I just began working with pipes and forks. Thanks.

Comment: Your requirement is that Process A creates Process B, and Process B creates Process C. Remember that `fork()` splits the program into two processes at that point. What that means is if you just do `fork(); fork();`, you now have 4 processes. `fork();` after that, and you get 8. Instead, you want controlled forks. Inside Process B's code (when `fork() == 0` the first time), you'll want to have a `fork();` again. And those are the only two forks you should have. Also, don't forget that `fork()` can fail. You should verify the result isn't 0 by assigning the result to a variable or using `switch`

Answer (score 0):

In your programm multithreading does not make any sense at all as every thread has either to wait until he gets the next value or is calculating at the moment because every thread needs the result of the previous one. That would mean that there are always two threads waiting and one currently running.

That's also the problem of your programm. The threads run asynchronously and are not waiting for the previous one to complete it's calculation.

Comment: How can I modify the program in order to solve the problem? Only with sleep() I think is not enough to order the threads.

Comment: In this case your programm is that simple that I guess a short sleep would do.

Comment: But actually you could use some kind of flag that each process raises after it's calculation to tell the next process to start: while (pass("father ", c2a[0], a2b[1], x) > 0){
        x=x+10; aRunning=0; bRunning=1; while(aRunning==0){}}

Comment: I just noticed something else: your x variable will be copied for each process -> everyone has it's own instance of it. So you have to use shared memory for it.

Comment: Short sleep or not, a good friend opened my eyes. So, the 3 forks remains with their if instructions, the incrementation step of x was modified, and for each fork, the unuseful descriptors were closed. The declaration of  x variable remains where it is, but it will be initialized after each fork begins with the propper value given in the problem .An important step was to modify pass function in order to display the winner.  By the way, variable n - declared in main, was declared again in pass (by mistake). I didn't notice that before. Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: @bolov Syntax analysis is not useful for anyone here.

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution is wrong because the processes A,B,C are brothers. The solution in which A is grandparent , B is parent and C is a child of B is the following:

This is the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int n;
int a2b[2], b2c[2], c2a[2], x;

void closeall(int* a, int* b, int* c)
{
    close(a[0]);
    close(a[1]);
    close(b[0]);
    close(b[1]);
    close(c[0]);
    close(c[1]);
}

int passData(char* id, int in, int out, int x)
{
    read(in, &n, sizeof(int));
    printf("%s %d \n", id, n); //  afisarea in plus pentru verificare
    if( n < 0 ) {
        printf ("WINNER is: %s %d\n ", id, n);
        return n;
    }
    n=n-x;
    printf("x= %d\n", x); //  afisarea in plus pentru verificare
    write(out, &n, sizeof(int));
    return n;
}


int main()

{
    pipe(a2b);
    pipe(b2c);
    pipe(c2a);

    srand(time(NULL));
    n=rand() % 1001 + 1000;
    x=0;


    write(c2a[1], &n, sizeof(int));


        while (passData("A", c2a[0], a2b[1], x) > 0){
            x=10;


    }

    if (fork() == 0){
        if (fork() == 0){
             while (passData("C", b2c[0], c2a[1], x) > 0){
             x=30;
             }

        while (passData("B", a2b[0], b2c[1], x) > 0){
            x=20;
        }


        wait(0);

        exit(0);
    }



    closeall(a2b, b2c,c2a);

    wait(0);
    wait(0);
    wait(0);
    return 0;
}
```